# Change Slingshot Launcher assigned key

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, slingshot

I changed the my slinghot launcher key form Super+Space to just the Super key using:

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu ['Super_L']"

I want to revert this process and change it back to Super+Space. How do I do it without using Xbindkeys as I have already tried that and failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Command Line Interface

You can use effectively the same method you used to change the shortcut in the first place to revert it:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings panel-main-menu "['<Super>space', '<Alt>F2']"`

reverting to the default of Super+Space or Alt+F2.

### Graphical `dconf-editor` Interface

Install `dconf-editor` with `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor` in a terminal window.  Browse using the left hand pane to `org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings`.  Find `panel-main-menu`, click it, and then "Set to Default" in the bottom pane. This will revert to the default hotkeys.